# How to change log level in /var/log/messages?

Tags: linux, logging, suse

I'm running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10, SP2 (SLES10 SP2), and am seeing a large number of what support calls cosmetic errors being logged to /var/log/messages.

Does anyone know of a way to change the log level in the /var/log/messages file?

Comment: Could not find the /etc/syslog.conf file.
Found /etc/syslog-ng.conf
I did not find this entry in the /etc/syslog-ng.conf file.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, edit `/etc/syslog.conf` (or `/etc/rsyslog.conf` depending on distro). There's a line

```
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warning;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages
```

remove *.=notice or *.=info or tweak it as you want.

```
$ man syslog.conf
```

will give you all the options you can use.

Don't forget to restart syslog daemon for changes to take effect.

Comment: In some distros, edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. This is in use in CentOS 7, at least.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what syslog daemon you are using.  From your comment about using `syslog-ng` I'd guess you should change this section in `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`:

```
filter f_messages {
        level(info,notice,warn)
            and not facility(auth,authpriv,cron,daemon,mail,news);
};
```

Per the other comment, you could try removing "`info,notice`" on the "`level()`" line.

(I’m guessing you are looking for something specific in `/var/log/messages` and having trouble finding it among all the other stuff?  If that’s the case, what you really *ought* to be doing is creating your own log file with exactly the messages you want.  This might be a little tricky and require some reading of the dreaded manuals, of course.)